# Docker unable to resolve Teradata database source url

Tags: docker, teradata, docker-machine, docker-network

I'm using docker to deploy a service which request Teradata for some information. The teradata only works on VPN which I'm connected now.

I'm using this syntax to connect to database :

```
 Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
 String serverURL = "jdbc:teradata://TDPG/LOGMECH=LDAP";
 String username = ldap_username;
 String password = ldap_password;
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(serverURL, username, password);
```

It's working when I connect from local environment, but when I use docker to deploy this service I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: TDPG: Name does not resolve
```

TDPG is the alias for database source and I don't have the IP for it. I don't know what is causing the problem because I'm able to access the url from local machine but couldn't from docker on the same machine.

I don't think it's a VPN problem because when I switch off VPN and then try to access from local machine I get different error (nodename nor server name specified) whereas the error inside docker remains same irrespective of I'm connected to VPN or not.

Someone please help.

Comment: You may need to include in your docker's /etc/hosts files the resolution for that "TDPG" address, or conversely, include the FQDN in place of the "TDPG" in that address. I've also run into the issue with servers inside the network that needed my company/VPN's DNS server listed in /etc/resolv.conf.